# How can I find only folders with ALL_CAPITAL letters in the name excluding hidden folders?

Tags: regex, video

I am in the middle of a project that was supposed to be simple and easy but I have been pulling my hair out for a week, so I am asking for your help.

**I am trying to simply count all folders that have names in ALL_CAPITAL letters.(excluding any hidden folders)**

The project:
My grandfather has been taking pictures and video for years and now has tens of thousands of slides and videos we are digitizing and are storing on a NAS drive. All videos are contained in their own folder which allows for complimentry files to be stored with them, for example a text document with info about the trip.

The naming convention I have adopted is simple. The folder with the actual video files is in ALL_CAPITAL letters with underscores between the words. Containing folders are in Regular_text with underscores for the spaces. So the drive looks like this...

*FOLDER:* Family_2004 
contains *FOLDER:* Bahama_Cruise
contains *FOLDER:* CRUISE_DAY_1 and CRUISE_(2004) and JOE_AND_SALLY_CRUISE

*FOLDER:* CRUISE_DAY_1
contains *FILE:* CRUISE_DAY_1.mp4 and memorable_day_1_events.txt

*FOLDER:* CRUISE_(2004)
contains *FOLDER:* AUDIO_TS and VIDEO_TS
contains unaltered DVD files including .IFO and .BUP and .VOB

This way using a WD media player he can click on any file with an ALL_CAPITAL name and see the video. He woud like to keep track of how many videos are on the system.

I thought I could do this very simply using windows 7 as follows... search type:folder -AUDIO_TS -VIDEO_TS. However as I understand it windows 7 can not do a case sensitive search.

I have used FileLocator Pro for years and then thought I should be able to use regex to define the search. I have tried dozens of combinations but I am obviously not good with regular expresions and can not figure out how to make a simple search to count only the folders with the names in ALL_CAPITALS excluding any hidden files.

EDIT:
As an addition to the request FileLocator uses a Perl compatible regexp syntax.

These are the only 2 tools I am familiar with I am not stuck on any particular method to do this. If anyone one could suggest a way I could accomplish this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: All this story is missing one major point. The regex which you tried! fwiw, try `^[A-Z_0-9()]+$` as regex.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry about the length. I put the request right up top in bold for those who did not need or want to read through the background info. I guess the idea did not work very well. I have tried dozens of variations of regex in FileLocator none of which produced any valuable results, so I did not post any.

Comment: Your suggestion produced the following Family_2004, Bahama_Cruise, CRUISE_DAY_1, CRUISE_(2004), JOE_AND_SALLY_CRUISE, AUDIO_TS, VIDEO_TS. It did filter all actual files and hidden folders but not the names in lower case. I tried adding ^a-z every way I could think of, with no success. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I'll recommend that you instead convert the names of files/folders into strings, and use powershell to capture the strings matching pattern I wrote above.